# React props.children is not array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html), if a component has multiple children, this.props.children should be an array.

I have the following component:

```
export class Two extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(Array.isArray(this.props.children)); // false
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

};
```

Which I pass children to in another component's render() method:

```
<Two>
    <Img src="/photos/tomato.jpg"/>
    <Img src="/photos/tomato.jpg"/>
</Two>
```

Why is this.props.children not an array? More importantly, how can I get it to be one?

Comment: Also according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children), children is an opaque data structure.

Comment: What do you need to do with `this.props.children`?  If you want to iterate all the children than you have tools like in [React Children utilities](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children).

Comment: Is it because Img is capitalized?

Comment: @ZackArgyle Img is a custom component that I created

Comment: @DavinTryon That ultimately worked but it feels a bit clunky for something that I imagine is quite common. This did the trick: `let children = [];
  React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function(child) {
   children.push(child);
  });`

Comment: I would argue that when using React's containment composition: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment. In this scenario where we are injecting the contents into another component, props.children will always be an an array of objects. Although I'm not sure of this fact, so I think this should be it's own question. Maybe I will create one.

Answer (score 57):

Found a better solution to this after some digging in the [React.Children source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/487cc586f709b059e68c54968d1ee08193740781/src/isomorphic/children/ReactChildren.js). It looks like a `.toArray()` method has been added in React 0.14, soon to be released.

Once it is out we will be able to simply do something like this:

```
let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
```

It's documented in https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: There's actually an entire API for working with props.children: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children. props.children itself is considered "opaque" and no assumptions should be made about its implementation - see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/751.

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution. It will render all children, one or more.

```
const BigMama = ({ children, styles, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      styles={{styles}}
      className={(className ? className : '')}
    >
    {
      React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
        <React.Fragment>{child}</React.Fragment>)
    }
  </div>)
}


<BigMama
  styles={{border: 'solid groove'}}
  className='bass-player'
>
  <h1>Foo</h1>
  <h2>Bar</h2>
  <h3>Baz</h3>
  <h4>Impossibru!</h4>
<BigMama>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something with the results (eg. render the array in a list), this is how you can use children.  The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) talk about how the `map` function works with children, as it's an opaque structure.

```
export const List = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {React.Children.map(children, child => <li>{child}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

So then you can call

```
<List>
  {item.name}
  {item.price}
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways and some are mentioned above already but if you wanna keep it simple and want to achieve this without any utility then below should work

```js
const content = [
  <Img src="/photos/tomato.jpg"/>,
  <Img src="/photos/tomato.jpg"/>
];

<Two>
  {content}
</Two>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find the spread syntax useful in this case. Have you tried it out?

```
<div>
    { [...this.props.children] }
</div>
```

Combine with map to manipulate the output.

```
<div>
    { [...this.props.children].map(obj => <div style="someStyling"> {obj} </div> ) }
</div>
```

Comment: I love this, but in typescript I get: `Type 'ReactNode' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)` sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because is it a DOM node? Try `console.log(this.props.children)` you will notice that it logged a array of objects (note that each object contains information of the child element of the component). I read that node and array are not the same tho they have a same format. Visit [Javascript DOMNode List](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp#:%7E:text=A%20node%20list%20is%20not,its%20nodes%20like%20an%20array.) for more information.