# REACT: Dynamic list rendering without array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to achieve with this question is to not pass the <li> tag in the App.js component. The only solution I've found with the REACT documentation is to use an array and map it to <li> tag. The thing is that doing it this way is not so clean.

App.js

```js
const App = () => {
  <Component>
    <li>
      <Link> Item 1 </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link> Item 2 </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link> Item 3 </Link>
    </li>
  </Component>
}
```

Component.js

```js
const Component = ({children}) => {
  return(
    <ul>{children}</ul>
  )
}
```

**Edit:** My components where cluttered with unnecessary tags.

Comment: Shouldn't `App.js` start with `const App =` ? (twice)

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a clearer example for what you want. I don't think it's clear at all what you are asking for. If you are rendering an unordered list you'll need to render a list item (`li`) as a child, then you can render any child element/component from there.

Comment: I'll agree not clear. That being said, you may consider a react fragment `<>stuff</>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) to make the `<li>` be added to each of the children, instead of making each child responsible to do it for themselves:

```
const App = () => {
  <Component>
    <Item />
    <Item />
  </Component>
}
```

```
const Component = ({children}) => {
  return(
    <ul>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => <li key={i}>{child}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: The `children` prop isn't an array, so you can't just map like this.

Comment: The comment of @DrewReese is correct. Nonetheless, there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672966/react-props-children-is-not-array) to convert the **children prop** into an array. `React.Children.map(children, (...))`

Comment: Ah you're both right, it was late... now fixed.